# Matplotlib scale y axis based on manually zoomed x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a lot of data that is correlated on the x axis but are all center around very different Y values. The data is also very long on the x so its hard to see details. I want to be able to set the x axis manually for the data set and then have the plot rescale the y axis itself based on the values of the data points that lie inside that manually set x axis.

Is this possible with matplotlib?

Comment: if you use `ax.set_aspect('equal')` you get such behavior...

Comment: thanks for the response, could you expand on this a bit?

do i need to get the axes first? How do you tell it that the x axis is the one to determine the y axis?

Comment: wont the set_aspect('equal') cause the y axis to be the same as the x axis? I dont want this behavior, the y axis has a much larger range than the x axis and on completely different values. I want to set the x axis limits and then have the y scale itself so i can easily see the data that lays within the x axis i set. Also i have no relation between the size of the x axis and the size of the y so i can't just set some aspect ratio

Comment: I am not aware of an existing option for this. You could hook into the matplotlib DrawEvent, check if the x-axis scale changed `ax.get_xlim()` and set the y-axis accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment from mdurant I wrote some minimal example as a starting point for you:

```py
import pylab as pl

pl.figure()
x = pl.rand(30)
x.sort()
y =  pl.sin(2 * pl.pi * x) + 0.1 * pl.randn(30)
pl.plot(x, y)

def ondraw(event):
    xlim = pl.gca().get_xlim()
    y_sel = y[pl.logical_and(x > xlim[0], x < xlim[1])]
    pl.gca().set_ylim((y_sel.min(), y_sel.max()))

pl.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', ondraw)
```

You might want to add more [events](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) to handle mouse movements etc.

Some comments:

- I'm using `pylab`, since it provides useful functions for generating examle data. But you can import the `matplotlib` library as well.
- The `ondraw` event handler gets the current x limits of the current axes `gca()`, selects `y` values with corresponding `x` coordinates within the x limits and sets new y limits determined by the minimum and maximum y value of selected coordinates.
- With `mpl_connect` we attach the event handler to the current axes. Every time the axes is drawn - e.g. due to new plotting commands or manual user interaction - it calls `ondraw` to update the y limits.

Comment: Can you explain your code a little more? You seem to use pylab but i am using matplotlib.

Comment: @user3123955: Please have a look into the [matplotlib documentation on event handling](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html). PyLab is basically [a different interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib) to NumPy and matplotlib, often used by former Matlab users. You can use both. The commands are almost identical.