# Pandas side by side line plot with different y-axis values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

i'm plotting 3 side by side line plots:

```
data = df_chuck_from_db.groupby('day')['price'].agg(['min','max','mean'])
data.reset_index(inplace=True)

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, sharey=True, figsize=(16,6))

data.plot(x='day', y='mean', c='lightsteelblue', ax=ax1)
data.plot(x='day', y='max', c='lightsteelblue', ax=ax2)
data.plot(x='day', y='min', c='lightsteelblue', ax=ax3)
```

which give me the output:
[image]

and what i would like to achieve would be this:
[image]

can the y-axis be tweaked on the first plot (mean) to be different from the other 2 plots?

Comment: This should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461608/matplotlib-fixing-x-axis-scale-and-autoscale-y-axis

Comment: thanks @vestland. It's the thread already proposed by Serge. It's what i was looking for. Thought it would be easier, though :)