# How to rescale x-axis limited Matplotlib plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I plot data using Matplotlib and limit the x-axis to a smaller range, Matplotlib still uses the same y-axis limits as before the x-axis limitation. For example

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
y = x**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
plt.show()
```

gives the following plot:

[image: Plot image]

I would expect that the y-axis approximately ranges from ~0 to ~4, since these are the new data limits in the x-limited region. Is this considered to be a bug? And if not, is there a simple way to achieve the desired output (without truncation of the NumPy array to the desired x-range)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to automatically set the y-axis limits after limiting the x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67599526/how-to-automatically-set-the-y-axis-limits-after-limiting-the-x-axis)

Comment: Not completely, since all solutions require either a rather complex functions or truncating the data. Therefore, the answer is probably: No, there is no simple way.

Comment: Using a boolean mask array is fairly simple.