# matplotlib autoscale(axis='y') after slicing plot with set_xlim()

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

As a demonstration, I'm plotting x^0 through x^9 with x values in range from 10 to 20.

Then I'm slicing those images so that I have 9 slices:

x = (10 to 11), (11 to 12) etc. to (18 to 19)

I want my images cropped so that y values are always spread from top to bottom in each slice, but what I'm getting is autoscale always scales to the full dataset rather than the current slice.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


# create some test data
for i in range(10):
    x = np.arange(10,20)
    y = x**i
    plt.plot(x,y,c='red',marker='.',ms=2)

# get all x values in chart and reduce to a sorted list set
xd = [] 
for n in range(len(plt.gca().get_lines())):
        line = plt.gca().get_lines()[n]
        xd.append((line.get_xdata()).tolist())
xd = [item for sublist in xd for item in sublist]
xd = sorted(list(set(xd)))

# attempt to plot slices of x with autoscaled y
ax = plt.gca()
for i in range(len(xd)-1):
    ax.set_xlim([xd[i],xd[i+1]])
    ax.axes.autoscale(enable=True,axis='y', tight=True)
    plt.pause(1) #timing
    #uncommenting the next line will create nine tiny (6kb) image files
    #plt.savefig(('image_%s.png' % i), bbox_inches=0, dpi=48)
```

In my actual application, I'm attempting to generate 100k tiny images in this manner as a database from stochastic data.  For every x there are between 2 and 200 y values.   Then I'm using OpenCV to image match new images to the best fit amongst the historical database.

Its critical that the y values are stretched from top to bottom in each image for OpenCV to find a good match.

if it helps my x values will always be int() type and equally spaced

ETA: I've attempted to implement some of the solutions here but have made no progress:

[Matplotlib - fixing x axis scale and autoscale y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461608/matplotlib-fixing-x-axis-scale-and-autoscale-y-axis?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Matplotlib scale y axis based on manually zoomed x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534524/matplotlib-scale-y-axis-based-on-manually-zoomed-x-axis?noredirect=1&lq=1)

but at least I've learned:

> Autoscaling always uses the full range of the data, so the y-axis is
>   scaled by full extent of the y-data, not just what's within the
>   x-limits.

still no solution that works here though

```
def autoscale_y()
```

presented by @DanHickstein

gives me:

```
h = np.max(y_displayed) - np.min(y_displayed)
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity
```

From those links, I'm unsure where to implement @Joe Kington's mask solution in my for loops.

I'm now working with @bernie solution proposed here to get Y values given X:

[How to extract points from a graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850845/how-to-extract-points-from-a-graph)

maybe then I can set_ylim() given the min and max Y values at that X manually?

This would be so much easier if there was a way to autoscale within the defined xlim as a standard matplotlib method

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue last night by creating a dictionary with x's as keys and a respective list of y's as values.

This occurs as the data is created by the function y=x**i

in essence I'm creating dictionary structure pseudocode:

```
data[x0] = [x0y1,x0y2,x0y3....]
data[x1] = [x1y1,x1y2,x1y3....]
data[x2] = [x2y1,x2y2,x2y3....]
etc.
```

I can later reference all the y values at any given x.  From there, find the min and max y value for the left and right side of my slice to manually set ylim.  If your xlim slice was more than one x segment wide you'd have to repeat the process for each respective x slice within your xlim.  In my instance, my x slices are exactly one segment wide.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# move my range function out of my data creation loop
x = np.arange(10,20,1)

# create a dictionary of my data with x values as keys
data = {}
for i in range(len(x)):
   data[x[i]]=[]

# create some test data
for i in range(10):
    y = x**i
    plt.plot(x,y,c='red',marker='.',ms=2)

    # store my y data to my data dictionary as its created
    xx = x[-len(y):]
    for j in range(len(xx)):
        data[xx[j]].append(y[j])

# get all x values in chart and reduce to a sorted list set
xd = [] 
for n in range(len(plt.gca().get_lines())):
        line = plt.gca().get_lines()[n]
        xd.append((line.get_xdata()).tolist())
xd = [item for sublist in xd for item in sublist]
xd = sorted(list(set(xd)))

# attempt to plot slices of x with autoscaled y
ax = plt.gca()
for i in range(len(xd)-1):
    ax.set_xlim([xd[i],xd[i+1]])

    # reference my min and max y values by left and right borders of x slice
    ymin = min(min(data[xd[i]]), min(data[xd[i+1]]))
    ymax = max(max(data[xd[i]]), max(data[xd[i+1]]))
    # manually set y limits
    ax.set_ylim([ymin,ymax])

    #eliminate my autoscale call
    #ax.axes.autoscale(enable=True,axis='y', tight=True)
    plt.pause(1) #timing
```

Now when it plots, y is autoscaled to the x slice, not the entire dataset.